# Is there a way to know the REAL msg.sender?

Tags: solidity, require, authentication

I want to know the real msg.sender of the transaction. Which this means is, if I use `truffle console` I can change the msg.sender by using `{from: another address}`. So let's say my address is A, and another user's address is B. And B created an sale auction for he's item1. But by using `truffle console`, I can cancel this auction by, `cancelAuction(item1_id, {from: B})` despite the REAL msg.sender is me(the address A). How can I check the real msg.sender(A) from the function's `require()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a real blockchain, you can't send from whatever account you want. You can only  send as an address for which you know the private key.

So "the real `msg.sender`" is just `msg.sender`. It cannot be spoofed.